# google map thinks i'm sending automated requests

Tags: google-maps

My web site uses google maps

and i'm simply showing the map with some markers for a search results
we are stil in beta so only employees know where the site is, so there is not much traffic.

what happens when the page is called we do a search then render the page in js we build the marker to be added but ...

sometimes we get the error 503 when trying to load the map
 with this content

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Sorry...</title>
<style>body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><table>
<tr><td><b><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>G</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#f3c518 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>g</font><font face=times color=#30a72f size=10>l</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>e</font></b></td>
<td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%">
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div></td></tr>
</table></div>
<div style="margin-left: 4em;">
<h1>We're sorry...</h1>
<p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries.
To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
</p>

<form action="Captcha" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="continue" value="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&apikey [blablabla]">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="928[blablabla]6">
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td valign="top" align="left">
<font color="#aa1002">
<b>To continue searching, please type the characters you see below:</b>
</font>
<input type="text" name="captcha" value="" id="captcha" size="12">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="I'm human!">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div align="right">
<img src="/sorry/image?id=928671[blablabla]6&amp;hl=en" border="1" alt="Please enable images on your browser.">
</div></td></tr>
</table>
</form>


</div>
<div style="margin-left: 4em;">
See <a href="http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=86640">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div>
<div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">
&copy; 2009 Google - <a href="http://www.google.com">Google Home</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what could be causing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that google really thinks that someone from my location is sending automated requests

if i go to maps.google.com is can see the captcha,

if i go on web sites that also use google maps, i can't see the map there either, so it's not related to my website.

my work around for the time being
in the google map div I will put a link to maps.google.com with instructions on how to resolve :
go to maps.google.com , fill the captcha , return to web site.

Answer (score 3):

I've never encountered a 503 (Bad Gateway) error from Google, but that HTML looks an awful lot like their 403 (Forbidden) error page.

I know of two ways to provoke a 403 error from Google fairly quickly:

1. Loading image tiles directly from
   your own code rather than from the
   API.
2. Using "Save web page complete" on an
   example file and then using the old
   saved copy of the Google API code as the basis for your new page
   instead of loading a fresh copy of
   the API in the documented manner.

In both cases the actual mechanism is the same. Google change the map tile version numbers every few weeks. If the tile server sees you making requests for the wrong tile version, it will block you after a few hundred such tile requests.

Also, the blocks are typically counted against your IP address, not your web page. It's possible that somebody sharing your IP address is doing something like the above on a different web page. You see the effect when you visit any page that shows the same Google API maptype.

You remain blocked for 24 hours or until the Captcha is successfully completed on a first offence. Persistent offenders don't get the Captcha option, and Google say that they might get blocked permanently.

Comment: I think it's a 503 - Service unavailable
(http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html or for email http://code.google.com/apis/apps/faq.html#email503)

my block lasts about 5-10 minutes, then back to normal

what do you mean by 'Loading image tiles directly from your own code rather than from the API.'
and  'Google change the map tile version numbers every few weeks. If the tile server sees you making requests for the wrong tile version, it will block you after a few hundred such tile requests.' 
How do i know which version i'm requesting ?

Comment: I load my script like so :
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v2&amp;key=[MYKEY]" type="text/javascript"></script> 

how could I allow my users to  respond to the captcha ? that would be nice

thanks

Comment: also it happens a lot more in ie than chrome or firefox
could be just the way I used it but could be an hint

Answer (score 3):

If you can't solve the problem you could try contacting Google with [this form](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/request.py?contact_type=ban).

Answer (score 0):

(Wanted to add a comment to the previous answer but it's not possible, so here is a new answer with a bit more info.)

I have the same problem from Telefonica's network in Spain. I can confirm that this issue exists on all websites that use google maps, including google's own examples in the documentation. Solving the captcha on maps.google.com helps in firefox, safari and chrome, but with internet explorer the maps still don't work on other websites after solving the captcha.

When using Vodafone's mobile broadand google maps work on all pages in all browsers and it doesn't require me to solve a captcha on maps.google.com.