# Google maps javascript api 503 when loading tiles (with captcha)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, recaptcha

My company's app is using google maps javascript api (v3) and today some people in the office have started seeing missing tiles in our app's map.

I checked the console and there's indeed a 503 error. When opening the failing url from the browser I see a page with a captcha and a message by google saying that there's too much traffic from my ip and offers a captcha.

Clicking on the captcha doesn't solve the problem in my app though...

My question is:
I understand what the problem is, but is there anyway to get around it? Why does google think i'm a bot? I checked our quotas on the api console and we're not passing them..

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: Can you please show us your code or self contained example so we can help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Franco, can't really create a self contained example since this only recreates on our office IP.

Comment: Hey I've found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523773/google-map-thinks-im-sending-automated-requests looks like it could be related to your issue, if not try searching the site I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: Are you using an API key? If you do, and if you can't post any code (and therefore nobody can reproduce the error), then I suggest you contact Google support directly.

Comment: Something in your code is triggering Google anti-abuse systems. You should analyze how you zoom, pan etc. Are zoom and panning change programmatically in your app or it's pure user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that this [`503 http error`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) is indeed your quota exceed, it's just that google statistics have not been updated yet... or you fired to many per second

Another reason it could be that you made too many incorrect requests or some other reason that got you blocked.

Try again tomorrow and chances are it will work again just don't fire to many requests.

Comment: Google has specific messages for that usually, such as `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` and such.